# FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW vs FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH?

Tags: php, filter, validation, sanitization

In reference to the `filter_var` function in PHP 5:

I have visited its documentation at: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php, but I still have this question:

What are the **exact** differences?

For simpler clarification, please provide an example.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The flags are explained in a [different page of the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php).

`FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` strips bytes in the input that have a numerical value <32, most notably [null bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) and other [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) such as the ASCII bell. This is a good idea if you intend to pass an input to another application which uses [null-terminated strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). In general, characters with a Unicode codepoint lower than 32 should not occur in user input, except for the newline characters 10 and 13.

`FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH` strips bytes in the input that have a numerical value >127. In almost every encoding, those bytes represent non-ASCII characters such as `ä`, `¿`, `堆` etc. Passing this flag can be a band-aid for [broken string encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), which can become a [security vulnerability](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22243). However, non-ASCII characters are to be expected in virtually all user input.

To summarize:

```
filter_var("\0aä\x80", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) == "\0aä\x80"
filter_var("\0aä\x80", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW) == "aä\x80"
filter_var("\0aä\x80", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH) == "\0a"
filter_var("\0aä\x80", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
           FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH) == "a"
```

Comment: It would be great if there was a STRIP_LOW_EXCEPT_NEWLINB flag, since there is a use case for keeping newline characters from textarea-fields. Alas, there is none, so that special case must be handled.

Comment: something is not  working in your examples, please have a look https://eval.in/935865

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Thank you for the note. I have fixed the answer. Escapes in string literals only work in double quotes in php.

Answer (score 3):

```
FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW
```

Remove characters with `ASCII` value `< 32`

```
FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH
```

Remove characters with `ASCII` value `> 127`